# Probably a REPLAY attack? OPENVPN

Tags: openvpn

Since a while my normal OPENVPN connection became really problematic...
There are Three symptoms:

1. Extremely slow connection,
2. My official bandwidth is getting fully occupied...
3. When I use UDP, this error is all over logs (as you can see more than 200,000 times in few minutes):

   `Thu May 30 20:43:12 2019 AEAD Decrypt error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #207142 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings`
4. When I Use TCP I get even slower connection (again full bandwidth usage) but no error in logs.

No tun-mtu nor MSSFix altered the outcome...
(Tried lower mtu like 1300 on both sides with no success.)

Configs are pretty normal and the same as I was using for past year but all of a sudden everything is messed up.

Does it looks like a REPLAY ATTACK?
If true, Are there any solutions for it?

Comment: Sounds like a problem on the other end of the tunnel.  Do you have access to it?

Comment: Yes, I can configure both server and client side...

Comment: Never attribute to malice that which can be explained by a network loop and lack of spanning tree protocol.